# import json to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this json file

```
{
    "5927803e892d4c459f2992a3a1ac2ead.16": {
        "lat": 57.532696,
        "lng": 9.949331
    },
    "e25fe65e4fe4468db1361213ba1a376b.16": {
        "lat": 57.501783,
        "lng": 9.947415,
        "name": "Vidstrup Train Station",
        "disabled": false
    },
    "dcd8b44bd0f3478cb2d99c8d5115ba50.16": {
        "lat": 57.480323,
        "lng": 9.968769,
        "name": "Vellingshøj Station",
        "disabled": false
    }
}
```

I have a working php file to import it
but I really would like the ID also
my problem is that in the json file
there are no name for it like "id":""

```
 <?php  
 //  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx", "Rails");  
 $filename = "location-export.json";  
 $data = file_get_contents($filename);  
 $array = json_decode($data, true);  
 foreach($array as $row)  
 {  
      $sql = "INSERT INTO location(location_lat, location_lng, location_name, location_mission) VALUES ('".$row["lat"]."', '".$row["lng"]."','".$row["name"]."', '".$row["mission"]."')";       
      mysqli_query($connect, $sql);       
 }  
 echo "Data Inserted";  
 ?>
```

Comment: What is the id, are you looking for `foreach($array as $key => $row)`? And you should use a prepared statement to avoid sql injection.

Comment: this is the id's I want from the file
"5927803e892d4c459f2992a3a1ac2ead.16"
"e25fe65e4fe4468db1361213ba1a376b.16":
"dcd8b44bd0f3478cb2d99c8d5115ba50.16":

it's just a ine time import

Comment: So in my sql i will have location_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as follows

```
 foreach($array as $id => $row)  
 {  
      $sql = "INSERT INTO location(id, location_lat, location_lng, location_name, location_mission) VALUES ('{$id}','".$row["lat"]."', '".$row["lng"]."','".$row["name"]."', '".$row["mission"]."')";       
      mysqli_query($connect, $sql);       
 }  
 echo "Data Inserted";  
 ?>
```

but of course this is totally insecure (and possibly slower) than using prepared statements.

You should try

```
$stmt = mysql_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO location(id, location_lat, location_lng, location_name, location_mission) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

 foreach($array as $id => $row)  
 {  
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssss", $id,  $row["lat"], ....);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


 }
```

Comment: ohh
just checked the full script now
and it only reads the first line now
so I only get the first record now

Comment: nopes, there isn't anything in my answer to cause the whole file not to be read or decoded. That part happens in your original code `$data = file_get_contents($filename);  
 $array = json_decode($data, true);  ` and that should be preserved